# Digital Metaphors Report Builder Surround Group Inside Box

Tags: delphi, report, reportbuilder

I'm interested in creating a report that contains a group in it.

I'd like the group to be enclosed in a box where the box surrounds the group in every page I've tried this using lines and placing them in such a way that there is one on the group header, two on the sides, and lastly, one on the footer.

The issue always appears when the data in the group overflows to a new page, and the footer of the group does not print. Ultimately I'd like to go from something that looks like a box missing the bottom line to one that is fully closed on every page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I have understood your question, but try taking a look at using a region, with all members of the group in it, including the lines/shape used, you can then group the items together.

Comment: Actually yes, that answered my question perfectly! Using a region causes the groups to be enclosed at all times! Thanks so much!
(I'll post a picture of what I meant when I have enough reputation)